NES 6502 assembly: CMP in NMI doesn't work
I have an NES program that does the following in an infinite loop:

Checks the controller input of both controllers for the A button
If the A button is pressed, it branches to a label that sets a RAM address value that NMI compares to a set value, and if that RAM address is set, it shows the sprite VIA OAM RAM. Otherwise, it just sets the sprites Y offscreen, and ends the NMI.

Here is the code:
.segment "HEADER"
    .byte "NES"     ;identification string
    .byte $1A
    .byte $02       ;amount of PRG ROM in 16K units
    .byte $01       ;amount of CHR ROM in 8K units
    .byte $00       ;mapper and mirroing
    .byte $00, $00, $00, $00
    .byte $00, $00, $00, $00, $00
.segment "ZEROPAGE"

.segment "STARTUP"

    (All the same boilerplate code from the link below)

    INFLOOP:
        LDA #$00 ;00 supposed to be but lets just try this
        STA $20
        CheckAButtonEitherController:
    ; Strobe both controllers to reset their state
            LDA #$01
            STA $4016       ; Strobe both controllers
            LDA #$00
            STA $4016       ; Clear strobe

            LDA $4016       ; Read the state of the first button on controller 1
            AND #$01        ; Mask to isolate A button
            BNE AButtonPressed ; Branch if A button is pressed on controller 1
            LDA $4017       ; Read the state of the first button on controller 2
            AND #$01        ; Mask to isolate A button
            BNE AButtonPressed ; Branch if A button is pressed on controller 2
            JMP Done

        AButtonPressed:
            LDA #$40
            STA $0020
            JMP INFLOOP

        Done:
            JMP INFLOOP
NMI:
    LDA #$02    ;LOAD SPRITE RANGE
    STA $4014 
    LDX #$00
    Clearspr:
        STA $0200, x
        INX 
        CPX #$00
        BNE Clearspr
    LDA $20 
    CMP #$00 ;supposed to be 40, because that's what the controller sets, but that doesn't work. Instead, this is the value from the start of the INFLOOP. But that doesn't work
    BEQ SETSPRITE
    END_NMI:
        LDA #$F0 ;Y POS(OFFSCREEN)
        STA $2004 ;WRITE TO OAMDATA
        LDA #$10 ;TILE INDEX
        STA $2004 ;WRITE TO OAMDATA
        LDA #$00 ;ATTRIBUTES
        STA $2004 ;WRITE TO OAMDATA
        LDA #$40;XPOS
        STA $2004 ;WRITE TO OAMDATA
        :
        LDA #$02 ;CLEAN UP 
        STA $4014 ;CLEAN UP
        RTI
    SETSPRITE:
        LDA #$10
        STA $2004
        LDA #$11
        STA $2004
        LDA #$00
        STA $2004
        LDA #$21
        STA $2004
        BPL :-
.segment "VECTORS"
    .word NMI
    .word RESET
.segment "CHARS"
    .incbin "rom.chr"

Here is my boilerplate:https://github.com/InkboxSoftware/NESGuide
(I use the same charecter ROM aswell)
What happens: Nothing.
Whats supposed to happen: The sprite be always visible, because the RAM address is constantly set to hex $00 and compared to #$00 during the NMI routine.
Here's my compiler script:
ca65 main.s -o main.o -t nes
ld65 main.o -o main.nes -t nes

My emulator: FCEUX
Why does it do this? This makes 0 sense. RAM watcher in fceux shows that the RAM is being written, so why isn't it working?
EDIT:
(All same from original code)
INFLOOP:        
  LDA $4016         
  ORA $4017         
  STA $20       
  JMP INFLOOP 
NMI:    
  LDA #$02  ;LOAD SPRITE RANGE  
  STA $4014     
  LDX #$00  
Clearspr:       
  STA $0200, x      
  INX       
  CPX #$00      
  BNE Clearspr  
  LDA #1    
  BIT $20   
  BNE SETSPRITE     
END_NMI:                 

(same code as original because im running out of characters)                

  LDA #$02  ;CLEAN UP       
  STA $4014 ;CLEAN UP       
  RTI 
SETSPRITE:      
  LDA #$10      
  STA $2004         
  LDA #$11      
  STA $2004         
  LDA #$00      
  STA $2004         
  LDA #$21      
  STA $2004         
  BPL 


Does the sprite show if you simply copy that part of the code out of the NMI into the main loop? Also note your NMI does not preserve the registers and that after a button press the value of $20 only changes for a very short time since you JMP INFLOOP which immediately zeroes it again so you have to get very lucky for the NMI to see it.

What i want this code to do is to display the sprite WHILE the a button is held. Is there any way to modify the code to make that happen?

Sure, you could write the button state to that memory location e.g. LDA $4016; ORA $4017; STA $20 (remove all other writes to $20) then in the NMI just check the LSB, e.g. LDA #1; BIT $20; BNE SETSPRITE

I did this but it didn't work

Does the code work if you run it unconditionally?

If i add just a JMP to the SETSPRITE, it still doesn't work. If i move it to the INFLOOP after the controller check, it works, but it is very glitchy and puts some garbage next to it

I included the code from your comment above into the answer.

Looks like you code reset value at address $20 to 0 at the beginning of INFLOOP no matter if button is pressed or not. Because of that NMI routine may not detect #$40. Your code set #$40 to address $20 for a fraction of time, which is not enough for NMI code to catch up.
